# Is redstone deterministic?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

In circuits not using pseudo-random 'dice-roll' type randomizers (i.e. a fast clock that the player stops to produce a random state), is the output state always the same for the same input state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

Load up [this schematic](http://tommedley.com/files/Non-deterministic.schematic) using [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/).

[image]It is a block transporter, pressing the button triggers the pistons to transport the block horizontally.

Sometimes, the block will traverse the entire system:

[image]

Sometimes it will stop at a random point some way along.

[image]

Comment: It is supposed to be deterministic, however sometimes the map can't keep up with the redstone due to inefficiencies in the code and block update order. This is especially bad in multiplayer.

Comment: Agreed. I'll upvote if you give some more explanation about how redstone is *usually* deterministic, and what might cause failure to occur.

Comment: Would delaying the system more cause systems like this to be more efficient and less likely to fail?

Comment: @agweber Possibly, I timed this machine so that *every tick counts*, a single blip and it'll fail - and clearly those blips *do* happen!